# SQL Server : query to pivot and show not set values

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

I have a SQL Server table with 3 columns: `UserID, SettingID, SettingValue`.

Example

```
UserID | SettingID | Value
1      | 10        |0
1      | 11        |1
1      | 14        |0
2      | 10        |1
2      | 13        |1
```

1. Need to convert into columns per Setting ID
2. Can be that there is no row for Setting ID -> want to grab that non exisitng and Display as "not set"

Desired result:

```
UserID | Setting10 | Setting11 | Setting13 | Setting14
1      |  Off      |  On       |  not set  |  off
2      |  On       |  not set  |  on       |  not set
```

The list of SettingID is given, there is no need to analyze and automatically find them.

Have no idea how to approach this

Answer (score 0):

As you say the list of `settingid` is fixed, you can get the desired result with conditional aggregation.

```
select userid,
max(case when settingid = '10' then 
                                   case when value = 0 then 'Off'
                                        when value = 1 then 'On'
                                   else 'not set' end
    end) as setting10,
--proceed similarly for other settings
from yourtable
group by userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2370)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (UserID INT,  SettingID INT, Value INT )
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
(1      , 10        ,0),
(1      , 11        ,1),
(1      , 14        ,0),
(2      , 10        ,1),
(2      , 13        ,1)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT UserID
       ,COALESCE(  Setting10 , 'not set') Setting10 
       ,COALESCE(  Setting11 , 'not set') Setting11 
       ,COALESCE(  Setting13 , 'not set') Setting13
       ,COALESCE(  Setting14 , 'not set') Setting14
FROM (
    SELECT UserID 
         , 'Setting' + CAST(SettingID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Settings
         ,CASE Value WHEN 0 THEN 'off'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'on'
                END AS Value
    FROM @Table
    ) t
    PIVOT (MAX(Value)
           FOR Settings
           IN (Setting10 , Setting11 , Setting13 , Setting14)
          )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2370/0)**:

```
| UserID | Setting10 | Setting11 | Setting13 | Setting14 |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |       off |        on |   not set |       off |
|      2 |        on |   not set |        on |   not set |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your question

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnCaseName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
   + QUOTENAME(SettingID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SettingID FROM TableName) AS TableName

SELECT @ColumnCaseName= ISNULL(@ColumnCaseName + ',','') 
   + 'case when '+QUOTENAME(SettingID)+' = 0 then ''Off'' when  '+QUOTENAME(SettingID)+' = 1 then ''On''  else ''not set'' end  '
+ QUOTENAME(SettingID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SettingID FROM TableName) AS TableName

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
N'SELECT UserID, ' + @ColumnCaseName + '
FROM TableName
PIVOT(Max(Value) 
      FOR SettingID  IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This will work for any number of rows you add in your table.

Happy Coding